# swift do try catch not working

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to do a do, try, catch like so:

```
do {
   setQA = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [AnyObject]
   print(setQA)
}
catch _ {
    setQA = nil
    self.customAlert("Error")
}
```

and I am trying to call a method to use UIAlertController, but it never reaches it.

This does not even get by the try, my app crashes with this error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x1a1773968) to 'NSArray'
```

THis is an expected error that will sometimes occur pending on user data, I just dont my app to crash and just display the alert

Comment: It seems that the outermost object in your JSON is a dictionary, not an array. You can use a conditional downcast, but that still won't throw, it will just give nil for setQA

Comment: How do I do that @Paulw11

Comment: `[String: AnyObject]`

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is coming from this part of your code :

```
JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [AnyObject]
```

What you can do is something like that :

1. First check if you have actually receive some data from your sever :
2. Check the format of these data. Your code is crashing because it is trying to parse your JSON into a wrong format (here an array of object), so try to cover all possible cases.

result code would be something like this :

```
    if let realData = data as? Data{

             do {
                    if let setQA = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( realData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [AnyObject] {
                        //Check if the result is an Array
                    print(setQA)
                    }else if setQA = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( realData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        //Check if the result is a dictionnary
                    }
                }
                catch _ {
                    setQA = nil
                    self.customAlert("Error")
                }

            }else{
                //Check if you have at least some data
                self.customAlert("No data from server :(")
            }
}
```

In general, try to avoid the use of ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

`do/try/catch` will catch errors that are thrown by some other method, but it won't catch runtime exceptions, such as you are getting from the forced downcast. For example, if `data` was invalid JSON then an error will be thrown and caught. In your case it seems the JSON is valid, but it is a dictionary, not an array.

You want something like

```
setQA = nil
do {
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [AnyObject] {
        setQA = json
        print(setQA)
    } else {
        self.customAlert("Invalid response from server")
    }
} catch _ {
    self.customAlert("Error parsing JSON")
}
```